# Count no of vowels in a string

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote a program to count no of vowels in a string but its not efficient or optimized code.
Moreover it will not check caps vowels.

```
#include<iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
unsigned int vow_cnt=0;
char name[15]= "sijith aeu";
cout<<"Enter a name"<<endl;
cin>>name;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(name);i++)
{ 
  if(name[i] == 'a' || name[i] == 'e'||name[i] == 'i'||name[i] == 'o'||name[i] == 'u')
  { 
   vow_cnt++;
  }
 }
cout<<"vow_cnt"<< vow_cnt << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you proven it to be slow? Why do you want to optimize it?

Comment: `<iostream.h>` should be `<iostream>`. Also consider using `std::string`.

Comment: @Nikko doesn't really look like C does it. iostream, namespaces, cout, cin..

Comment: @harold char[15] instead of std::string, strlen

Comment: @Nikko: the difference being that C++ has arrays and `strlen`, whereas C doesn't have namespaces and `cout`. Hence this is C++, not C. You don't approve of the style, but that doesn't make it a different language.

Comment: No, it's just a question. Maybe it's from the school and they want him to use specifically char arrays and strlen, so it's more a C question. It's just to have correct answers. If the teacher expect the use of the C string library and you give him a functor and stl algorithm, what will be the result?

Comment: @Nikko: I tend to think that's at the questioner's risk. If he "does his homework" by copying an answer from SO that uses C++ concepts he hasn't been introduced to yet, then he'll be tripped up if it's obviously out of character with his other answers, or if he's asked to talk about it in a tutorial/class whatever. Or he'll get away with it, depends how much the teachers care. Since he's ostensibly learning C++, I think it's quite good if he's offered some idiomatic C++ solutions along with the simple C-looking ones. Maybe he can't use them yet, but it shows him where he's going.

Comment: Or to put it another way - I'm interested in answering people's questions and showing them either C or C++ or both, whatever they want to know about. I'm not desperately interested in whether my answers would score them marks in their homework assignment. So if they say C++ I think it's fine to throw high-power C++ concepts at them.

Comment: One way to optimize is to order your `if` expressions by popularity.  For example, move the 'e' comparison to the front.

Answer (score 5):

Considering your assumption that only a e i o u are vowels and that your string is all lowercase, try this:
Of course this going to fail horribly in unicode or for every language that has a different set of vowels.

```
bool is_vowel(char x) {
  // order by probability of occurrence in the target language
  // e.g. start with e for English
  // nb see comments for further details
  return (x == 'e' || ...); 
}

std::string foo;
long nbVowels = std::count_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), is_vowel);
```

Comment: "most common in languages that actually use it as a vowel". Most common in most languages, maybe. Sometimes the most common letter is `a` (Portuguese, maybe Spanish although I found two different Wikipedia pages that disagreed on that, maybe there's a difference between Castilian, Mexican etc). Not that it's essential to get the order exactly right, of course.

Comment: @Steve Probably that could be determined by some statistical analysis and optimized for the target language.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't test against `strlen(name)`. Compute the length once outside the loop.
2. Use an array of integers to map from characters to increments (0 or 1).
3. Ignore points 1 and 2.

Don't optimise code that waits for a person to enter their name and then loops over that name. Your exceedingly inefficient algorithm spends about 99.999% of its time waiting for user input.

Comment: true. however, this looks a lot like homework, and the task could be artificial here (algorithm complexity combined with C++ primer course?)

Comment: Depending on the implementation, the compiler can optimize away the multiple calls to `strlen(name)` (gcc does, the `strlen` function is marked as *pure* and in this particular case the compiler can prove that the result of the multiple calls to `strlen(name)` will all return the same value and thus perform a single call upfront into a injected temporary and then just use that value) --which is yet another reason to first *measure* and *profile* and then care about optimizing. Anyway it is a sound advice: whenever you *know* that the result won't change, avoid the calls.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see what compilers can hoist `strlen` for themselves. `name` and `vow_cnt` are both automatic variables, hence cannot possibly be aliased, so it's not all that difficult for an optimizer to see that it's a valid optimization.

Answer (score 3):

- Mainly cleanupped. Clean code -> less bugs
- Use standard algorithms (find, count_if)
- Use std::string
- Check errors
- Use up-to-date headers

#### [See it live: http://ideone.com/E6QJy](http://ideone.com/E6QJy)

**Edit** By popular demand: perhaps I should show case conversion in proper style (?) too :)
The link shows output for the following input

```
krk#!@#^&*
AEIOUÄËÏÖÜÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃ°Øªº
aeiouäëïöüáéíóúàèìòùâêîôûã°øªº
```

For the record, [this is what we *had*](http://ideone.com/fLHvg):

```
static inline bool isvowel(char ch)
{
        static const std::string vowels("aeiouEAIOU");
        return vowels.end() != std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch);
}
```

My new contraption is far more enterprisey, and it supports your custom character types too! Behold:

```
#include <iostream>   // avoid old style MSVC++ header!
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

template <typename T=char>
    struct isvowel
{
    bool operator()(T ch) const
    {
        static std::basic_string<T> vowels("aeiouäëïöüáéíóúàèìòùâêîôûã°øªº"); // etc. for specific languages...
        static int _init = 0;

        while (!_init++) // not thread safe :)
        {
            vowels.reserve(vowels.size()*2);
            // upper case dynamically based on locale, e.g. AEIOUÄËÏÖÜÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃ°Øªº
            std::transform(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), std::back_inserter(vowels), (int(*)(int)) std::toupper);
        }
        return vowels.end() != std::find(vowels.begin(), vowels.end(), ch);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "German"); // set relevant locale for case conversions
    std::cout << "Enter a name: ";

    std::string name;

    while (std::cin >> name) // handle errors?
    {
        size_t vow_cnt = std::count_if(name.begin(), name.end(), isvowel<char>());
        std::cout << "vow_cnt: " << vow_cnt << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now if anyone can share [authoritative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_language#Vowels) code to get [the collection of vowels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_alphabet#Short_vowels) according to a specific locale... It'll be even [more enterprisey](http://www.sql-und-xml.de/unicode-database/latin-extended-b.html). Woot.

Comment: More comprehensive than my answer although lacking the whole "Vowels are certainly not what you think they are." touch :)

Comment: @pmr: true. I didn't miss it. I chose not to address it. If I knew about a locale facility to classify vowels, I'd have used it

Comment: @pmr: Ok, I caved. You're right. Made the code much more entertaining. Also much more involved. _If performance is the highest goal, I really suggest minimizing the character set to avoid wasting cache lines_ <whistle/>

Comment: If you're going to argue what is and isn't a vowel, maybe some analysis of adjacent letters to decide on `y` ;-)

Comment: A perfect specimen of the "hard problem in trivial disguise"-genus.

Comment: I think you're wrong when it comes to std :: string being more efficient, it's much slower.

Comment: @Abody97: slower than what, when doing what? Of course it heavily depends. Have you profiled the difference? Note that I suggest a static const copy, which should be _exactly_ as fast as a char array. I suggest making the array shorter, and of course frequency optimizing the order would be supreme (if not beyond the scope for this question)

Answer (score 2):

Just the important part:

```
const char *p = name;
while(*p)
  switch(*p++) 
  {
  case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
  case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
    vow_cnt++;
  }
```

Comment: You could eliminate some code and use `tolower` or `toupper` before the `switch`.  Less code, less testing, less that can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A look-up table *might* be faster:

```
char isvowel[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 }; // or int instead of char, try both
isvowel['a'] = 1;
isvowel['e'] = 1;
isvowel['i'] = 1;
isvowel['o'] = 1;
isvowel['u'] = 1;
isvowel['A'] = 1;
isvowel['E'] = 1;
isvowel['I'] = 1;
isvowel['O'] = 1;
isvowel['U'] = 1;

...

  if (isvowel[(unsigned)name[i]]) vow_cnt++;
```

You could also try letting the compiler decide how to optimize, by using a switch:

```
switch(name[i]) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
    case 'A':
    case 'E':
    case 'I':
    case 'O':
    case 'U':
        ++vow_cnt;
    default:
}
```

Then again, either or both might be slower. You'd have to test it with more realistic data, since "optimizing" a program that only processes one short string is pretty futile. It will be effectively instantaneous whatever you do, so don't waste your own time. Performance only matters if you're processing a lot of data, so either one enormous string or lots of strings.

ASCII has a trick, that `name[i]` is a particular letter (either case) if and only if `name[i] | 0x20` is that letter (lower case). You can use that to halve the number of case labels or (with care) the size of the lookup table. That may or may not affect performance.

If you want to try a completely different approach, see how it performs, you can take the complicated logic and branching out of the loop:

```
size_t charcounts[UCHAR_MAX+1] = { 0 };
char *p = name;

while (*p) {
    ++charcounts[(unsigned)*p];
    ++p;
}

vow_cnt = charcounts['a'] + charcounts['e'] + ... + charcounts['U'];
```

This is likely to be slower for short strings, since the `charcounts` array has to be cleared for each string you test. It has a chance for large amounts of data, though.

Comment: What about using `tolower` or `toupper` to remove half the cases?

Comment: @Thomas: yes, that's the clear, sensible, maintainable way to write it. But if you can assume ASCII then the `0x20` trick is potentially faster because it cuts a corner. For example it transforms `[` to `{`, which we don't care about just for this purpose but `tolower` has to avoid.

Comment: +1, but vow_count+=isvowel[(unsigned)name[i]] will be fastest. Both faster than the if, and slightly faster than switch/case (jumps).

Answer (score 0):

For things like that, I have two generic functions, which you can use for any purpose (even commericial), and the third one is the one adapted to your needs (untested though):

```
const bool IsChar(const char Target, const char Source, const bool CaseInsensitive = false)
{
    if(Target == Source){ return true; }
    if(CaseInsensitive)
    {
        if( (Source >= 'A') && (Source <= 'Z') )
        {
            if( (Source+32) == Target ){ return true; }
        }

        if( (Source >= 'a') && (Source <= 'z') )
        {
            if( (Source-32) == Target ){ return true; }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

const bool IsCompareChar(const char C, const char CompareChars[], const bool CaseInsensitive = false)
{
    while((*CompareChars))
    {
        if(IsChar(C,*CompareChars,CaseInsensitive)){ return true; }
        CompareChars++;
    }
    return false;
}

const unsigned int CountVowels(const char Array[], const unsigned int Length)
{
    unsigned int N = 0, NumberOfVowels = 0;
    while(N < Length)
    {
        if(IsCompareChar(Array[N],"aioue",true))
        {
            NumberOfVowels++;
        }
    }
    return NumberOfVowels;
}
```

However, given what you're doing is meant to teach you about coding, I would advise, rather than copying and pasting the given code, you write your own version, given a specific function for a role is more optimised than a generic function.

In main, you'd merely call it by:

```
CountVowels(Array,strlen(Array);
```

CountVowels will merely return the count. Although the function itself can be modified to count any character, both upper and lower case etc etc.

Comment: mmm. no disrespect, but in my neighbourhood this would certainly count as _bad code_. Don't hard code character encodings, don't hard code case conversions, use standard naming conventions, don't pass a cstr as a char[]; input to CountVowels supports embedded null chars, CompareChars doesn't. Gratuitous use of multiple exit points. <thinks/>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
string vowels = "aeiou"
string query = "dsdlfjsdofkpdsofkdsfdfsoedede"  ;
int countVowels =0;
for(int i =0 ; i < query.length() ; i++)
{
  int j=0;
  while(j < vowels.length())
  {
     if(query[i] == vowels[j++])
     {
        countVowels++,break;
     }


   } 
}
```

Comment: The proper type to index into a `std::string` is `std::string::size_type`, not `int`. I would try to get into the habit of using pre-increment by default. (Because there's types where the difference matters for performance.) And never write your own loops if you can use those the std lib provides for you (`std::string::find_first_of()`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some answers recommended using std :: string, which I don't. It's much slower than using the regular char [] array structure. For counting the vowels more efficiently, you can use a letter frequency count instead, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
const int MAXN = 100; // Or whatever you want it to be.
char x[ MAXN ];
int freq[ 26 + 1 ];
char vowels[ ] = "aeiouy" // Or whatever you want it to be too :D
void fillFrequency() {
    for( int i = 0; i <= 26; i ++ ) {
        freq[ i ] = 0;
    }
    int len = strlen( x );
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) { 
        freq[ x[ i ] - 'a' ] ++;
    }
}
int main() {
    cin >> x;
    fillFrequency();
    int nVowels = strlen( vowels );
    int ans = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < nVowels; i ++ ) {
        ans += freq[ vowels[ i ] - 'a' ];
    }
    cout << ans << '\n';
    return 0; // That's it! :D
}
```

Hope that helps :D

Comment: I dig the letter frequency thingie, I decided not to touch on it since it already seemed way beyond the scope of the question (seeing the question mode, I suspect it is totally irrelevant how 'efficient' the implementation really is)

Comment: Also, if you mean your version is way faster, it'll be because because it does way less (it doesn't use locale case conversions). Also, if you are going to do the `fillFrequency` for every single input, you'll be slower than just running it without it. You'd need to run it on _some representative body if input strings_ up front (and then leave it at that)