# Looping through each element of a vector

Tags: c++

so let's say i have a vector, wich contains 4 elemens [string elements]. I need to loop through the vector first , then through each element , loop through an array of chars [vowels]
and to count how many vowels does that word contain.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) 
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++) 
       {
         for(int v = 0 ; v < sizeof( vowels ) / sizeof( vowels[0] ); v++)
          if(//blabla)
       }
    }
```

so my question is, how can i loop through each word , i mean `b[i][j]` is the right way to do that?

if yes, this form , will work great? :

```
if(b[i][j] == vowels[v]) {
//blabla
}
```

thanks.

Comment: almost, you mean: if(b[i][j] == vowels[v])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more advanced way to go about this, which you should take a look at if you're serious about learning C++: don't use indices and random access, use high-level STL functions. Consider:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool is_vowel(char s) {
    static const char vowels[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    const char* vbegin = vowels;
    const char* vend = vowels + sizeof(vowels)/sizeof(char);
    return (std::find(vbegin, vend, s) != vend);
}

std::string::difference_type count_vowels(const std::string& s) {
    return std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_vowel);
}

template <class T> void printval(const T& obj) { std::cout << obj << std::endl; }

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> b;
    b.push_back("test");
    b.push_back("aeolian");
    b.push_back("Mxyzptlk");

    std::vector<int> counts(b.size());
    std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), counts.begin(), count_vowels);
    std::for_each(counts.begin(), counts.end(), printval<int>);

    int total = std::accumulate(counts.begin(), counts.end(), 0);
    printval(total);
    return 0;
}
```

Where the loops you've written correspond roughly to these lines:

```
 std::transform(b.begin(), b.end(), counts.begin(), count_vowels);
 ..
 std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_vowel);
 ..
 std::find(vbegin, vend, s)
```

This uses a high-level functional/generic programming idiom that C++ is not always elegant at pulling off IMO. But in this case it works fine.

See [Count no of vowels in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429309/count-no-of-vowels-in-a-string) for a rundown of solutions to part of the problem I think you're trying to solve. You can see a variety of acceptable looping/iteration techniques on display there as well.

Comment: yea , i see now, it's an advanced method. But why my method isn't good? i'm just curious, there are ~ 7 lines of code wich count the vowels and print them out , but in this case there are more than 7. Is it about performance not quantity?

Comment: Nah, both will probably perform about the same, and your method isn't necessarily bad. You do have to juggle several index variables and manage the iteration yourself though, and that's where dumb mistakes can sneak in. Also, once you get used to reading the higher-level stuff, I think you'll find it's a bit easier to maintain, since the code expresses a little more directly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, as far as # of lines of code, note that my code snippet has the full context attached and fleshes out the example. I think in this case it will end up being about the same size either way, but excluding braces and includes I think the functional approach might actually come out a bit more compact. (For more advanced examples it may end up significantly shorter.) And as you go through the functional approach, you may also find that the decomposition you're forced to do makes your code cleaner and more reusable.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<T>` defines `T operator[](int)`. This means you can access a vector `x`'s element `i` via `x[i]`.

`std::string` defines `char operator[](int)`, which returns the `char` at that position within the string.

So if you have an `std::vector<std::string>` called `x`, `x[i][j]` will return the `j`th character of the string in the `i`th position of the vector.

This is not the idiomatic C++ way to do this - the most common means would be iterators (the `.begin()` and `.end()` calls). But since vector access is constant time (as is string-character access) it's not a huge deal.

Comment: "... it's not a huge deal."

Considering that vector::iterator is implemented with a pointer, amd that the most the underlying platform, `itrator::operator++()` is "pointer aritmetic" wile int::operator++() is register immediate instruction.

Considering some processor have instruction implemented in firmware for looping and indexing, the index version (respect to the iterator version) although not generic can even be faster!